# PHP determine if user is landing from external or internalpage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to serve two slightly different type of contents
in case 
A: the user is circulating thru my website, 
B: the user is coming directly from a google search or else

there is any way in PHP to do this? or apache/htaccess?

Comment: Check HTTP referrer header in htaccess and redirect as needed?

Comment: mmm probably storing session is easier and more reliable...

Comment: @Francesco Then how do you populate the session variable initially?

Comment: @Drakes `if(isset($_SESSION['blah_blah'])){ \\internal }else{ \\external + add session variable } ` ?

Comment: @Manikiran My point was you need to check the http referer header before setting the session.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "mywebsite.com") !== false)
    {
        // User has come from another page on my site
    }
    else
    {
        // User  has come from Google or someplace else
    }
}
```

Note that `HTTP_REFERER` may not have a value in all cases.

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.